# What does arch mean in lwIP file names?

Tags: lwip

What does `arch` mean in `lwIP` file names? I tried to guess and think about "archive" or "archaic" but those seem different.

Comment: corrected grammar and formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`arch` in `lwIP` comes from **architecture**. As written in [documentation of sys_arch.txt in GitHub](https://github.com/yarrick/lwip/blob/master/doc/sys_arch.txt):

> The operating system emulation layer is located in two files, cc.h and sys_arch.c. The operating system emulation layer provides a common interface
>   between the lwIP code and the underlying operating system kernel. The
>   general idea is that porting lwIP to new ***arch*itectures** requires only
>   small changes to a few header files and a new **sys_arch** implementation.